# Getting Started On PIC and Web GUI?

Tags: pic

I've some basic knowledge on how to program PIC microcontrollers in the past I've used a LCD and a keyboard to make a clock alarm.

Recently I really got into Web development, mostly on SQL, PHP, HTML and some other basic stuff.

What I want to achieve is to create a GUI using web languages, that I can access using any computer within the same network. ( I don't know wether I should host the server in a computer that is connected to a PIC or if I should host the web server in the pic).

So the real question is: Where do I start so I can get documentation on some projects that used a similar set up to what I want to achieve.

Comment: Start with a PIC32. I'd suggest a WF32 board from Digilent, since it has WiFi built in, an SD card for holding lots of data, etc.  You won't serve much with a PIC32, but you can do a basic control / data interface, or maybe write a SOAP server or something for getting the data into another system on a PC...

Comment: In the future things will be easier. With the new PIC32MZ chips resources are much easier.  I'm part of a crew porting 4.4BSD-Lite to it at the moment, to give a full blown Unix environment on a PIC.

Comment: Runing a full webserver with PHP and MySQL may be too heavy. I have created a web server on a PIC18 once using JALv2. It didn't have a PHP backend, that was all done in JAL. It could do basic things. You could also look in to Raspberry Pi. If you're going to stick with PIC, Microchip has a full [TCP/IP stack](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en537041). But one important part in your question seems to be missing: a GUI *to what*? Relays? LEDs? Buttons and switches? Or more complex things?